# How can I plug in this simple SQL logic to an already existing script correctly?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Currently I am working on a sql script in informatica powercenter, the current script is this

```sql
ltrim(rtrim(Sur_Co))||

ltrim(rtrim(Seqe_N))||

rpad(ltrim(rtrim(Ct_Num)),30,' ')||

**iif(isnull(ltrim(rtrim(ent_Tx_ID))),rpad(' ',20,' '),
rpad(ltrim(rtrim(ent_Tx_ID)),20,' '))||**

**iif(isnull(ltrim(rtrim(ent_Tx_ID_Q))),rpad(' ',2,' '),
rpad(ltrim(rtrim(ent_Tx_ID_Q)),2,' '))||**
```

ETC

I dont need the iif is null logic for **ent_Tx_ID and ent_Tx_ID_Q** anymore,
I just need  to **always give the value of empty spaces for these two columns** specifically like this,

```sql
**ent_Tx_ID = RPAD(' ',20,' ')
ent_Tx_ID_Q = RPAD(' ',2,' ')**
```

how would I edit this logic into that script?

Comment: Please tag your question properly!!!  Since when SQL Server has `lpad` and `rpad`, whatever it does.

Comment: Sorry Eric, I was not aware as I am not a master in coding yet, that is why I am here. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below concatenations directly in informatica,

```
ltrim(rtrim(Sur_Co))||
ltrim(rtrim(Seqe_N))||
rpad(ltrim(rtrim(Ct_Num)),30,' ')||
' 20 ' || ' 30 '
```